# Why does Rails `includes` method not add included model to attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into a strange issue with nested rails models related to the `includes` method. I'm attempting to simply move an item from one object to its parent like so:

**Current:**

```
[
    {
        "created_on": "2014-09-11T15:52:34-04:00",
        "id": 8,
        "mail_notification": false,
        "project_id": 2,
        "user_id": 15,
        "member_roles": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "inherited_from": null,
                "member_id": 8,
                "role_id": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Needed:**

```
[
    {
        "created_on": "2014-09-11T15:52:34-04:00",
        "id": 8,
        "mail_notification": false,
        "project_id": 2,
        "user_id": 15,
        "role_id": 3
    }
]
```

For some reason, when I loop through the current object, It strips out the `:member_roles`. Case in point:

```
members = Member.includes(:member_roles).find_all_by_project_id(@project)

# Contains :member_roles
puts members.to_json(include: [:member_roles])
    #=> [{"created_on":"2014-09-11T15:52:34-04:00","id":8,"mail_notification":false,"project_id":2,"user_id":15,"member_roles":[{"id":10,"inherited_from":null,"member_id":8,"role_id":3}]}]

# Does not contain :member_roles
puts members.first.attributes
    #=> {"id"=>8, "user_id"=>15, "project_id"=>2, "created_on"=>Thu, 11 Sep 2014 15:52:34 EDT -04:00, "mail_notification"=>false}
```

Why does the `:member_roles` object disappear?

Comment: Because `member_roles` is not part of member attributes. Its an association.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do what you expect.

Member.includes(:member_roles) is eager loading your relation (ie it fetchs all the member_roles instances required by the member collection when you actually use on of this object the first time)

to_json(include: [:member_roles]) is including the json reprensation of the related model in the parent member model json.

What you describe is called method delegation ([Module.delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)), but since you have a one to many relation between your 2 models you cannot do it